How can I select four points A, B, C, D and M so that MA = 3, MB = 5, MC = 7, MD = 9 and reduce the time to compile
This is mycode
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
eq1 = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == 3^2 && x y z != 0}, {x,
      y, z}, Integers];
eq2 = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == 5^2 && x y z != 0}, {x,
      y, z}, Integers];
eq3 = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == 7^2 && x y z != 0}, {x,
      y, z}, Integers];
eq4 = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == 9^2 && 
      x y z != 0}, {x, y, z}, Integers];
newSet = 
  Table[{eq1[[i]], eq2[[i]], eq3[[i]], eq4[[i]]}, {i, 1, 
    Min[Length[eq1], Length[eq2], Length[eq3], Length[eq4]]}];
results = 
  Table[Module[{pA = newSet[[i, 1]], pB = newSet[[i, 2]], 
     pC = newSet[[i, 3]], pD = newSet[[i, 4]], pM, Msolution}, 
    pM = {x, y, z};
    Msolution = {x, y, z} /. 
      Solve[{EuclideanDistance[pA, pM] == 3, 
        EuclideanDistance[pB, pM] == 5, 
        EuclideanDistance[pC, pM] == 7, 
        EuclideanDistance[pD, pM] == 9}, {x, y, z}, Integers];
    {pA, pB, pC, pD, Msolution}], {i, 1, Length[newSet]}];
results


{{{-2, 2, 3}, {-4, 2, 3}, {-6, 2, 3}, {-8, 2, 3}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{-1,
1, 1}, {-3, -1, 3}, {-5, -1, 1}, {-7, -2, 2}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{-1,
1, 5}, {-3, 2, 6}, {-5, -1, 5}, {-7, -2, 4}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{-1, 3,
1}, {-3, 5, 3}, {-5, 4, 6}, {-7, 1, -1}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{-1, 3,
5}, {-2, -2, 3}, {-5, 5, 1}, {-7, 1, 7}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{-1, 4,
2}, {-2, 2, -1}, {-5, 5, 5}, {-7, 3, -1}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{-1, 4,
4}, {-2, 2, 7}, {-2, -4, 1}, {-7, 3, 7}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{1, -1,
3}, {-2, 6, 3}, {-2, -4, 5}, {-7, 6, 2}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{1, 2,
6}, {1, -3, 3}, {-2, 4, -3}, {-7, 6, 4}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{1, 5,
3}, {1, -2, 6}, {-2, 4, 9}, {-6, -2, -1}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{2, 4,
1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-2, 8, 1}, {-6, -2, 7}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{2, 4,
5}, {1, -1, 7}, {-2, 8, 5}, {-6, 6, -1}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{3, 1,
1}, {1, 2, -2}, {-1, -4, 6}, {-6, 6, 7}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{3, 1,
5}, {1, 2, 8}, {-1, -1, -3}, {-5, -4, 6}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{3, 3,
1}, {1, 5, -1}, {-1, -1, 9}, {-5, -1, -3}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{3, 3,
5}, {1, 5, 7}, {-1, 5, -3}, {-5, -1, 9}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{3, 4,
2}, {1, 6, 6}, {-1, 5, 9}, {-5, 5, -3}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{3, 4,
4}, {1, 7, 3}, {-1, 8, 6}, {-5, 5, 9}, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {{4, 2,
3}, {4, -2, 3}, {1, -5, 3}, {-5, 8, 6}, {{1, 2, 3}}}}

How can I reduce the time to get the result?

eq4 looks weird.  it contains ^2^2.

Choose all points on the x axis and set x:  m:0,  a:3, b:5, c::7, d:9

@A.Kato Thank you very much.

For this problem brute force can find instances, e.g.
v = Range[3, 9, 2];
f[u_] := Select[# . # == u^2 &][Tuples[Range[-u, u], 3]]
pts = f /@ v;
Times @@ (Length /@ pts)
i[] := With[{p = RandomChoice /@ pts, m = {0, 0, 0}},
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, #] & /@ v, Opacity[1], 
    PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[m], Yellow, Point[p], 
    Line[{m, #}] & /@ p}, Background -> Black, 
   PlotLabel -> Join[{m}, p]]]

Here are 9 instances:
Grid[Partition[Table[i[], 9], 3], Frame -> All]


There are 4957200 cases. This could be reduced,  of course, by regarding order and sign as equivalent solutions.
The "reduced" core cases:
red[u_] := DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Abs[u]]
reduced = red /@ pts


